# Cargo build - dependencies files not found

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo

I'm using files such as `log4rs.yaml` and `.env`.

When using `cargo build`, the `log4rs.yaml` is no longer found.

```
    log4rs::init_file("log4rs.yaml", Default::default()).unwrap();

    miscellaneous::check_env_variable();
```

When I'm running the binaries I have the following error message:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: No such file or directory (os error 2)', src/main.rs:27:58
```

I tried using a build script without success, no sure how to proceed or if it is really the problem here

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to load file at runtime, or at build time (and if so, what do you want to do with its contents)?

Comment: Where are those files located relative to the `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: The idea is to be able to export logs later on. I need to add clipper later on. 
Files structure is as follows: 
src:
    - main.rs
    - .env
    - log4rs.yaml
    - stderr.log

Comment: They are all in the root folder with `Cargo.toml`

Answer (score 1):

Since you commented that the files are all located at the root of your project folder/directory what you might be (initially) be looking for is the environment variable called: `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR`.

This variables once read (`std::env::var`) will return a absolute path to folder/directory where your Cargo.toml lives.

The initial solution would look like this:

```rust
// ...
let cargo_path = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
let yaml_path = format!("{}/log4rs.yaml", cargo_path);
log4rs::init_file(yaml_path, Default::default()).unwrap();
// ...
```

The final solution might actually require you to (somehow):

1. Set a **default path** for `log4rs.yaml` outside of the development environment like: `~/.config/my_app/log4rs.yaml` or `~/.my_app/log4rs.yaml`
2. Add support to pass an arbitrary path for the `log4rs.yaml` file so we can source it from elsewhere (including inside your development folder).